# POST request using UrlFetchApp returns 404 where equivalent curl succeeds

Tags: php, http, curl, google-apps-script

I have a lengthy curl request that I'd like to emulate using UrlFetchApp:

```
curl 'https://example.com/index.php' -H 'Cookie: "XXXXXXXXXX"' -H 'Origin: https://example.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryK0ckVcd9Rae277Ae' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Referer: https://example.com/index.php' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundaryK0ckVcd9Rae277Ae\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="user"\r\n\r\nstaff\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryK0ckVcd9Rae277Ae\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="name"\r\n\r\nJohn Smith\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryK0ckVcd9Rae277Ae\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="staffid"\r\n\r\ne00000\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryK0ckVcd9Rae277Ae\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="preferred"\r\n\r\nEmail\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryK0ckVcd9Rae277Ae\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="phone"\r\n\r\n9999 9999\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryK0ckVcd9Rae277Ae\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="altemail"\r\n\r\njohn.smith@example.com\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryK0ckVcd9Rae277Ae\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"\r\n\r\nother\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryK0ckVcd9Rae277Ae\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="desc"\r\n\r\nTEST ONLY.\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryK0ckVcd9Rae277Ae\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="userfield"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryK0ckVcd9Rae277Ae\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="timezone"\r\n\r\nMon Mar 23 2015 10:28:33 GMT+1100 (AEDT)\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryK0ckVcd9Rae277Ae\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="browserstring"\r\n\r\nMozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryK0ckVcd9Rae277Ae\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename=""\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryK0ckVcd9Rae277Ae--\r\n' --compressed
```

I'm using the following UrlFetchApp code, which simply creates a payload and a header object, and encodes the payload as a binary blob:

```
function sendHttpPost(mailBody) {

   var reqPayload = '------WebKitFormBoundaryTIE5gBodnUrDhzC9\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="rmituser"\r\n\r\nstaff\r\n' + 
     '------WebKitFormBoundaryTIE5gBodnUrDhzC9\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="name"\r\n\r\nJohn Smith\r\n' + 
     '------WebKitFormBoundaryTIE5gBodnUrDhzC9\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="staffid"\r\n\r\nE00000\r\n' + 
     '------WebKitFormBoundaryTIE5gBodnUrDhzC9\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="phone"\r\n\r\n9999 9999\r\n' + 
     '------WebKitFormBoundaryTIE5gBodnUrDhzC9\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="altemail"\r\n\r\n\r\n' + 
     '------WebKitFormBoundaryTIE5gBodnUrDhzC9\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"\r\n\r\nother\r\n' + 
     '------WebKitFormBoundaryTIE5gBodnUrDhzC9\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="desc"\r\n\r\nTEST ONLY.\r\n' + 
     '------WebKitFormBoundaryTIE5gBodnUrDhzC9\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="userfield"\r\n\r\n\r\n' + 
     '------WebKitFormBoundaryTIE5gBodnUrDhzC9\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="timezone"\r\n\r\nThu Mar 19 2015 16:25:47 GMT+1100 (AEDT)\r\n' + 
     '------WebKitFormBoundaryTIE5gBodnUrDhzC9\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="browserstring"\r\n\r\nMozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36\r\n' + 
     '------WebKitFormBoundaryTIE5gBodnUrDhzC9\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename=""\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n\r\n' + 
     '------WebKitFormBoundaryTIE5gBodnUrDhzC9--\r\n';


  var reqHeaders = {

    'Cookie' : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'Origin' : 'https://example.com',
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryK0ckVcd9Rae277Ae',
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0',
    'Referer' : 'https://example.com/index.php',
    'Connection' : 'keep-alive' 

  };


  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(reqPayload);

  var options =
   {
     'method' : 'post',
     'payload' : blob.getBytes(),
     'headers' : reqHeaders,
     'muteHttpExceptions' : true

   };

   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.example.com/index.php", options); 

     Logger.log("Response Full: " + response);

 }
```

While I've altered some of the details in order to anonymise the example (including removing the cookie details), the two requests should be identical. The curl request works, and the UrlFetchApp request is constructed based on copying from the curl request. But the UrlFetchApp request returns 404.

I'd be keen to know if I've missed anything obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem here relates to firewalls.

In the instance where this didn't work, the UrlFetchApp target was behind a firewall. The curl command worked where this was sent from a terminal on a machine within that firewall. However, Google's Apps Script servers are outside that firewall, and hence the UrlFetchApp request fails.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining 'reqHeaders' but using 'reqHeadersMin'.

You say it's a PUT but I don't see an -X PUT in the curl command, so it would default to a GET I think. And you are defining you fetch() call to be a POST in the options.

Comment: Thanks for pickups re both 'reqHeaders' and the title of the question, which should have read 'post'.  Unfortunately in this instance correcting 'reqHeaders' doesn't fix the problem (as 'reqHeadersMin' was similarly defined).

The curl command is extracted from a POST action using the 'Copy as curl' command from a POST event in the Chrome network tab. Certainly when this event is copied to the command line, it achieves the desired POST action. Out of curiosity changed the fetch() method to GET, but no success  :/